# Serial.IsOpen failed - C# - Kinect

Tags: c#, arduino, kinect

I'am working on a Kinect User Interface gesture recognition.
I also used an arduino with eight leds connected to the digital pin. The leds simulate an output (like opening the doors).
So I used the program made bye [David Catuhe - Kinect Toolbox](https://kinecttoolbox.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest)
I wanted to add 6 gestures to be recognized, but this is not the purpose of my topic (of course if you are able to told it to me, don't hesitate).

So, when a gesture is recognised, I call my method to write something on the serial port :

```
            protected override void LookForGesture()
    {
        // Swipe to right
        if (ScanPositions((p1, p2) => Math.Abs(p2.Y - p1.Y) < SwipeMaximalHeight, // Height
            (p1, p2) => p2.X - p1.X > -0.01f, // Progression to right
            (p1, p2) => Math.Abs(p2.X - p1.X) > SwipeMinimalLength, // Length
            SwipeMininalDuration, SwipeMaximalDuration)) // Duration
        {
            RaiseGestureDetected("SwipeToRight");
            Serial.writeSerial("A");
            return;
        }
```

Can be found here : [Swipe Gesture Detector](https://kinecttoolbox.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Gestures/SwipeGestureDetector.cs)

Also here is my writeSerial Method :

```
            public void writeSerial(string dataToSend)
        {
            sw.Start();
            // Makes sure serial port is open before trying to write
            try
            {
                if (!(_serialPort.IsOpen)) _serialPort.Open();
                _serialPort.Write(dataToSend);
   
                Console.Write("data send");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error opening/writing to serial port :: " + ex.Message, "Error!");
                
            }
```

When I use the debug mode, the program right brake when the swipe is detected.
And so I can see by step into the writeSerial method, the program try to send something but the serial port is closed at this moment.

My serial communication should be ok, because it works with buttons.
In fact, I put several buttons. That way I don't have to reconnect my gesture all the time (and also because I can't do it at the moment, yet).

I can also provide my full code if you want.

Thank you very much.